# Is it possible to transfer MGS5 saved game from PS3 to Steam?

Tags: steam, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Is there any way I can transfer my MSG5 data from PS3 to Steam? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have read there isn't a way to if you have/had Metal Gear Solid Ground Zeros the save info would not transfer to PC. So I would imagine that the actual Game data won't transfer either.